# Print Datetime between Two timestamps in Java

Tags: java, time

Here is my requirement. Pretty sure there is an elegant way to do this. Need your help. I need to build a backend program to process and insert multiple dates into a table using start and end time selected by user.

**Input:**

```
StartTime: 11/26/2021 11:00 PM
EndTime: 11/28/2021 04:00 AM
```

**Output I am expecting**

```
11/26/2021 11:00 PM
11/26/2021 11:59 PM
11/27/2021 12:00 AM
11/27/2021 11:59 PM
11/28/2021 12:00 AM
11/28/2021 04:00 AM
```

**My Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String StartTime = "11/27/2021 11:00 PM";
        String EndTime = "11/29/2021 04:00 AM";
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
        LocalDate localStartDate = LocalDate.parse(StartTime, formatter);
        LocalDate localEndDate = LocalDate.parse(EndTime, formatter);

        LocalDateTime  localStartTime = LocalDateTime.parse(StartTime,formatter);
        LocalDateTime  localEndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(EndTime,formatter);
        
        
        List<LocalDateTime> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!localStartTime.isAfter(localEndTime)) {
            totalDates.add(localStartTime);
            totalDates.add(localStartTime.with(LocalTime.MAX));
            localStartTime = localStartTime.plusDays(1);
            localStartTime = localStartTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);
        }
        
        totalDates.add(localEndTime.with(LocalTime.MIN));
        totalDates.add(localEndTime);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < totalDates.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(totalDates.get(i) + "\n");
        }

    }
```

**My Output:**

```
2021-11-27T23:00
2021-11-27T23:59:59.999999999
2021-11-28T00:00
2021-11-28T23:59:59.999999999
2021-11-29T00:00
2021-11-29T23:59:59.999999999
2021-11-29T00:00
2021-11-29T04:00
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the MIN MAX and `plusDays`? I am baffled. If you explain your goal, perhaps we can better guide you. At a minimum, I suspect you need to learn about the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time.

Comment: I know half open approach. Here is my requirement, User enters two timestamps, I need convert that into  different outputs based on no of days between the user input.

Comment: Provide explanations as edits to your question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String startTime = "11/26/2021 11:00 PM";
String endTime = "11/28/2021 04:00 AM";

DateTimeFormatter dtf =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, dtf);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime, dtf);
```

- Start streaming the dates as given
- then create an inner stream by creating two `LocalDateTime` instances using the current `LocalDate` instance.

  - current datetime by `1 minute` before midnight
  - current datetime by `1 day` ahead of midnight
- then `flatMap` that stream and put the datetimes in a linked list.
- to finish, add the current start `LocalDateTime` to the beginning of the list
- and the ending `LocalDateTime` to the end of the list

```
List<LocalDateTime> list =
        start.toLocalDate().datesUntil(end.toLocalDate())
                .flatMap(date -> Stream.of(
                        date.atTime(23,59),
                        date.atTime(0,0).plusDays(1)))
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toCollection(LinkedList::new));
list.add(0, start);
list.add(end);
list.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.format(dtf)));
```

prints

```
11/26/2021 11:00 PM
11/26/2021 11:59 PM
11/27/2021 12:00 AM
11/27/2021 11:59 PM
11/28/2021 12:00 AM
11/28/2021 04:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to parse the output. Therefore you can use the already defined `DateTimeFormatter`, which has a `parse` method.

Code for the output:

```java
System.out.println(totalDates.get(i).format(formatter));
```

Also you have one additional line in your output. This one comes from the line where you set `localStartTime = localStartTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);`. Here i would suggest this change:

```java
LocalDateTime workingStartTime = localStartTime;

List<LocalDateTime> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
while (!workingStartTime.isAfter(localEndTime)) {
  if(!workingStartTime.equals(localStartTime)) {
    workingStartTime = workingStartTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);
  }
  totalDates.add(workingStartTime);
  totalDates.add(workingStartTime.with(LocalTime.MAX));
  workingStartTime = workingStartTime.plusDays(1);
}
```

**Edit: Solution using streams and flatMap**

Here is how you build the final List with streams (no extra adding of the last day is needed):

```java
List<LocalDateTime> totalDates = localStartTime.toLocalDate().datesUntil(localEndTime.toLocalDate().plusDays(1))
    .flatMap(date -> Stream.of(
        date.equals(localStartTime.toLocalDate()) ? LocalDateTime.of(date, localStartTime.toLocalTime()) : LocalDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIN),
        date.equals(localEndTime.toLocalDate()) ? LocalDateTime.of(date, localEndTime.toLocalTime()) : LocalDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MAX))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: At least your output was using the correct order based on ISO 8601 :-)

Comment: An alternative code for the output: `System.out.println(totalDates.get(i).format(formatter));`

Comment: @Oboe Thx for the input. Adapted the answer to this.

Comment: Solution using streams doesn't work. Getting below error. `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`

Comment: Did u also write the `Stream.of` part? It is important for `flatMap`. (worked in my IDE)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. If there are other elegant ways to do this.. Please let me know.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String StartTime = "02/27/2021 11:00 PM";
    String EndTime = "03/02/2021 01:00 PM";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    LocalDate localStartDate = LocalDate.parse(StartTime, formatter);
    LocalDate localEndDate = LocalDate.parse(EndTime, formatter);

    LocalDateTime localStartTime = LocalDateTime.parse(StartTime, formatter);
    LocalDateTime localEndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(EndTime, formatter);

    List<LocalDateTime> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
    while (localEndDate.isAfter(localStartDate)) {

        totalDates.add(localStartTime);
        totalDates.add(localStartTime.with(LocalTime.MAX));

        if (!localStartDate.equals(localEndDate)) {
            localStartTime = localStartTime.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
        }
        localStartDate = localStartDate.plusDays(1);

    }

    totalDates.add(localEndTime.with(LocalTime.MIN));
    totalDates.add(localEndTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalDates.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(formatter.format(totalDates.get(i)) + "\n");
    }
}
```